# Android Parse.com saving interrelated objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

In Parse I have the following 3 classes:
A, B, C. The relationships between them are the following:

**A has Relation< C >, C has Pointer< A > (A one-to-many C)**

**B has Relation< C >, C has Pointer< B > (B one-to-many C)**

When I'm saving new C object, I want it to be:

1) Saved as new C object with pointers to A and B

2) Saved in relation in object A

3) Saved in relation in object B

I guess it's quite a common architecure.

Right now I see only one solution: saving C, then adding C to A relation and saving A, then adding C to B relation and saving B. This is 3 requests and of course it's not reliable.

Is there a way to do it in 1 request?

Comment: You could probably get around it using cloud code. I just want to warn you that these cycle dependencies can cause headaches down the road. If you for instance enable local datastore, it will save objects recursively internally. Just a heads up. Think I read somewhere that you should stick to either pointer C -> (A, B) or relation A -> C, B -> C. Then using queries to get around it with the chosen solution.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks, Morten! Maybe I'm just to used to relational databases, can you tell me is it a good approach: I will have C with pointers to A, B (so your first solution), and there will be millions of C's in the table. If I then query one particular C by saying whereEqualsTo("A", A) and whereEqualsTo("B", B) - is it a good way to do it? I assume it will iterate though millions of C's to find the one I'm looking for. Or it's ok because Parse highly optimized for such requests?

Comment: It sounds ok to me. Actually just read their section on smart indexes in their android guide, and as far as I understood such kind of query should be able to take full advantage of their indexing. They have a whole section about performance in the Android guide now.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Gotcha. Thanks again, Morten